# On a FAT32 filesystem there was a file with ext2 filesystem image. Now it's truncated. How do I restore?

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, restore, fat32, ext2

How do I restore ext2 filesytem that was stored on FAT32 volume in a file which got truncated? Is there analogue of reiserfs's `--rebuild-tree` option to restore filesystem from content?

Comment: How do you store a filesystem on a filesystem?

Comment: One big 3GB file "debian.ext2" in root directory.